# A problem I met when reading Griffiths'Periods of Integrals on Algebraic Manifolds I

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am reading Griffiths' paper Periods of Integrals on Algebraic Manifolds I, and in section 2 I met some problems.

I wish that I could get some help here. My problem is that I cannot understand formula (2.19) and (2.20) on page $584$. I think that I know how to get the graph of a given morphism, but I cannot understand how the author could get the concrete formula (2.19) for its homology class. Thank you very much!

Here is the paper: http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/periodsofintegralI68.pdf

Comment: Although it is possible that your question may entice some kind-hearted user to go digging through the link you provided, you will have a much, much higher chance of success if you can ask a complete, succinct, self-contained, question.

Comment: @Lee Mosher Thank you for your advise.

Comment: @LeeMosher Is it possible to find people who are reading or interested in the same papers on this website? Thanks.